# ACL access abilities for Azure Containers and Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am looking at using azure Containers and Blobs to store images and videos for my website. I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179354.aspx which talks about the different ALC settings but it did not answer one of my questions. If a Container/Blob are set to "No public read access" the site says that only the account owner can read the data. Would this mean that people could not access it by the URL but my MVC Web App hosted on an Azure VM would be able to access it via URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please bear with me if the answer sounds a bit preachy & unnecessary lengthy :)

Essentially each resource (Blob Container, Blob) in Windows Azure has a unique URL and is accessible via REST API (thus accessible over http/https protocol). Wit ACL, you basically tell storage service whether or not to honor the request sent to serve the resource. To read more about authentication mechanism, you may find this link useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx.

When you set the ACL as `No public read access`, you're instructing storage service not to honor any anonymous requests. Only authenticated requests will be honored. To create an authenticated request, you would require your account name and key and create an authorization header which gets passed along with the request to access the request. If this authorization header is not present in your request, the request will be rejected.

So long story short, to answer your question **even your MVC application won't be able to access the blob via URL unless that authorization header is included in the request**. One possibility would be to explore [`Shared Access Signature (SAS)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj721951.aspx) functionality in blob storage. This would give time-bound restricted permissions to blobs in your storage. So what you would do is create a SAS URL for your blob in your MVC app using your account name and key and use that SAS URL in the application.

To further explain the concept of ACL, let's say you have a blob container called `mycontainer` and it has a blob called `myblob.txt` in a storage account named `myaccount`. For listing blobs in the container, the container URL would be `http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list` and the blob URL would be `http://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob.txt`. Following will be the behavior when you try to access these URLs directly through the browser with different ACL:

**No public read access**

Container URL - Error

Blob URL - Error

**Public read access for blobs only**

Container URL - Error

Blob URL - Success (will download the blob)

**Full public read access**

Container URL - Success (will show an XML document containing information about all blobs in the container)

Blob URL - Success (will download the blob)